# android calculating time difference for setting alarm

Tags: android, time

I'm developing a small alarm clock app and I need a way to calculate the time difference to be able to pass the interval to the alarmManager. I saw a lot of similar topics around here, so the question is: what is the best way of calculating the time difference for my purpose? 
I wrote that method to obtain time from the timepicker and calculate the difference but it's buggy since I get some crazy values while testing..

```
    public int CalculateInterval() {

    /*--- get the target time from the time picker ---*/
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tp.getChildAt(0);
    ViewGroup number1 = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(0);
    ViewGroup number2 = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(1);
    String hours = ((EditText) number1.getChildAt(1)).getText()
            .toString();
    String mins = ((EditText) number2.getChildAt(1)).getText()
            .toString();

    /*--- convert to integer values in ms ---*/
    int hrsInMillis = Integer.parseInt(hours) * 3600 * 1000;
    int mnsInMillis = Integer.parseInt(mins) * 60 * 100;

    /*--- obtain the current time in ms ---*/
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    int secondsInMillis = c.get(Calendar.SECOND) * 1000;
    int minutesInMillis = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 1000 * 60;
    int HoursInMillis = c.get(Calendar.HOUR) * 1000 * 3600;

    int current = secondsInMillis + minutesInMillis + HoursInMillis;

    /*--- calculate the difference ---*/
    int interval = (hrsInMillis + mnsInMillis) - current;

    return interval;
}
```

Comment: use Calendar.set and Calendar.getTimeInMillis()

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int secondsInMillis = c.get(Calendar.SECOND) * 1000;
int minutesInMillis = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 1000 * 60;
int HoursInMillis = c.get(Calendar.HOUR) * 1000 * 3600;
```

The above code is a bit unnecessary, and I would guess this is why you are getting "crazy values". Instead, get the `long` value from `c` and just subtract it with another `long`.

However, this is a bit of a trick since you currently only get the hours and minutes in millis.

Here's what I'd do (pseudocode):

```
set alarm to Calendar.getInstance()
set alarm.hour to Integer.parseInt(hours)
set alarm.minute to Integer.parseInt(mins)
set alarm.secs to 0
if alarm.before(now)
    add 1 day to alarm
endif
set difference to (alarm.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis())
```