# Calculate different seconds between two Timepickers

Tags: android, datetime, time

I tried to follow the suggestion here :

[android calculating time difference for setting alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124332/android-calculating-time-difference-for-setting-alarm)

So this is what i did :

```
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timeSchedule.getCurrentHour());
    start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeSchedule.getCurrentMinute());

    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, toTime.getCurrentHour());
    end.set(Calendar.MINUTE, toTime.getCurrentMinute());

    long startMillis = start.getTimeInMillis();
    long endMillis = end.getTimeInMillis();
    long diffSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(endMillis - startMillis);
```

Where `toTime` and `timeSchedule` is `TimePicker`. However, the result is incorrect. I suspect its because the `AM` and `PM`.

Please kindly help me, Thanks very much for your help.

UPDATE

Thanks to @Raghunandan, this is my current code :

```
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.set(Calendar.HOUR, timeSchedule.getCurrentHour());
    start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeSchedule.getCurrentMinute());

    if (start.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
        start.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    else
        start.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.set(Calendar.HOUR, toTime.getCurrentHour());
    end.set(Calendar.MINUTE, toTime.getCurrentMinute());

    if (end.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
        end.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    else
        end.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

    long startMillis = start.getTimeInMillis();
    long endMillis = end.getTimeInMillis();
    long diffSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(endMillis - startMillis);
```

Now the result is true if both of Timpickers are AM or PM. However, the result will be false (<0 or minus value) if, for example the user set 7 PM to 1 AM. What should i do?

Comment: try using `Calendar.HOUR`

Comment: @Raghunandan should it be HOUR_OF_DAY because of the AM PM?

Comment: @BlazeTama http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR

Comment: check the edited answer. You may also require a day picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6);
start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
start.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);

Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6); // 12 hour format
end.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
end.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM); // AM or PM

long startMillis = start.getTimeInMillis();
long endMillis = end.getTimeInMillis();
long diffSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(endMillis) - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(startMillis) ;
long diffHour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(endMillis) - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(startMillis) // 12 hour diff
```

Use `Calendar.Hour` for 12 hour format and `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` fro 24 hour format.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#AM_PM

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR

Edit:

7 pm to 1 am next day

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.set(Calendar.HOUR, 7);
start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
start.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = (start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);
end.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
end.set(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
end.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
end.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);

long startMillis = start.getTimeInMillis();
long endMillis = end.getTimeInMillis();
long diffSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(endMillis) - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(startMillis) ;
long diffHour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(endMillis) - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(startMillis) ;
```

Edit 2:

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

if (start.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
        start.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
else
        start.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
end.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
int day = (start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);
end.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);

if (end.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
        end.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
else
        end.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

long startMillis = start.getTimeInMillis();
long endMillis = end.getTimeInMillis();
long diffSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(endMillis - startMillis);
long diffHour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(endMillis) - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(startMillis) ;

Toast.makeText(this,""+diffHour, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Note: You may also require a day picker.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry i cant code right now. What do you mean by `start.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);`? My TimePicker have AM/PM and the user can choose it freely.

Comment: @BlazeTama di you check the links i posted ?? if its am set as am if its pm set as pm

Comment: @BlazeTama that's 7 pm today to next day 1 am right? then you need the day.

Comment: @BlazeTama also have a look @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html see if it fits your requirement!.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to add `int day = (start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);` but the problem still persists. Sorry what do you mean by requirement? Sorry to ask so many questions, i want to fix this my self but i have no idea..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71934/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-blaze-tama).